# Gesture recognizer is not active - UIImageView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have been looking at this code for a while and am still puzzled why it is not working.  Basically:
1. The user selects a table view cell
2. UIScrollView is invoke that contains a high res image or UIImage.
3.  The following is called  Map.m

```
#import "Map.h"

#define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100
#define ZOOM_STEP 1.5


@interface Map (UtilityMethods)
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
@end


@implementation Map

@synthesize imageScrollView, imageView;

- (void)loadView {
    NSLog(@"beginning of loadView in map.m");
    [super loadView];

    // set the tag for the image view
    [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
    imageScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.imageScrollView = nil;
    self.imageView = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [imageScrollView release];
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
}

/************************************** NOTE **************************************/
/* The following delegate method works around a known bug in zoomToRect:animated: */
/* In the next release after 3.0 this workaround will no longer be necessary      */
/**********************************************************************************/
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // single tap does nothing for now
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // double tap zooms in
    NSLog(@"beginning handleDoubleTap to zoom");
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // two-finger tap zooms out
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. 
    //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
    //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
}

@end
```

The gestures are not getting picked up from the image?  Please help

Answer (score 19):

`UIImageView` by default have touch & multi-touch interaction disabled. To detect touches on it you need to enable it yourself. So for your gesture recognizers to work you need to add this in `loadView`.

Try this in code -

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

This particular action can be enabled in XCode .`xib` file. For this goto that `xib` where the `imageView` is present and check the boxes which mention `user interaction` / `multi touch`.

[image]

Comment: So it is getting the event just not responding to them by zooming.  It also says:

Comment: its detecting the gestures however its not zooming the image or doing anything to it, rotating it etc.  It also says when I ctrl click on the image:Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active.

Comment: as your question was - gestures on uiimageview not recognizing, i think i have answered it. if you have any other doubts i suggest you write up another question. that way there is no confusion abt the question & answer